# Why is my github desktop fetching origin goes infinitely hang on?

Tags: github, fetch, github-actions, github-for-windows, github-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJHTg.png)
My github desktop gets stuck and infinitely load(actually takes like 10minutes) and goes to refreshing repository(also takes 10minutes). Whats happening? i need to back up my unity project, but I'm stucked on this problem. Could somebody help me?

I need to make my github desktop faster. Its too slow to use. push and pull in empty project takes 20minutes. Wish someone answer this problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Try to share code as text (in code blocks) not as image

Comment: Check if here: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4397 if you can find useful information

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SSH, [this post](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/10328#issuecomment-679315411) might fix the problem. I faced the same "infinite fetching origin" issue, and it solved it.

The problem could come from OpenSHH Authentication Agent being disabled by a Windows update. What I did was following the instructions in the post I linked, which was :

-enabling the OpenSHH Authentication Agent : type "Services" in the windows search bar, double-click on OpenSHH Authentication Agent, set "Startup type" to "Automatic", and apply changes.

-in GitHub desktop : Repository -> Repository settings, and paste the URL of my repository.

edit : WARNING. This is perhaps not the best solution, because if you were previously working with a SSH key, your Origin won't be your SSH key anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I went to `file -> options -> advanced` and disabled `Use system OpenSSH (Recommended)` checkbox, then clicked on `fetch` one more time, it asked passphare for my ssh key, I entered it and the issue was gone.

Not sure how does it affect working environment though.

[github desktop options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeO9w.png)